# How to see list of services run by mono-service

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, mono-service

I am running my Windows Service written in C# in Linux Ubuntu OS and I am really new to Linux.

What command should I enter in Terminal to see the list of services that is running by `mono-service`?

I tried `service --status-all` and `initctl list` as well, but it's not showing my service in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to see the services that are running under `mono` you can use the following command:

`ps ax | grep mono`

It will show you the service ID and name of the service.